# Right_aws ruby gem: Where do I have to store the AWS access keys and secret key?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, amazon-web-services, right-aws

Could you please tell me where do I have to store my AWS access key and secret access key when using Right_aws to access SDB?

Answer (score 1):

You would set it when you initialize the RightAws::SdbInterface:

[example/docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/right_aws/2.1.0/RightAws/SdbInterface%3ainitialize)

This means you could store your key/secret anywhere, including your config file if you're using rails.